# I just want to display the values in picklist on VF Page

Tags: visualforce, picklist, sobject, list

```
String soql = 'Select '+ pickField +' From '+ pickobjects;
list<SObject> sObj = new list<SObject>();
sObj = Database.Query(soql);
```

now i want to put the values of the list sObj into a picklist on vf page......how it is possible........?
i used following code

```
list<selectOption> fieldData = new list<selectOption>();
for (SObject so : soql) {
    fieldData.add( new selectOption(so,so));
}
```

getting error like Constructor not defined: [System.SelectOption].(SObject, SObject)

Comment: list<selectOption> fieldData = new list<selectOption>();
        for (SObject so : soql) {
            fieldData.add( new selectOption(so,so));
        }   getting error like Constructor not defined: [System.SelectOption].<Constructor>(LIST<System.SelectOption>, SObject)

Comment: There is no constructor of SelectOption which accepts two sObjects as parameters. See https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_System_SelectOption_constructors.htm

Answer (score 1):

The construction for SelectOption that you are trying to use is:

> `SelectOption option = new SelectOption(value, label);`
>   where value is the **String** that is returned to the controller if the option is selected by a user, and label is the **String** that is displayed to the user as the option choice.

In your code you are trying to call the constructor by passing in the SObject itself for both parameters. You would need to pass in a string value (perhaps the Name field of the SObject?).

i.e.

```
for (SObject so : soql) { 
  String displayName = String.valueOf(so.get('Name'));
  fieldData.add(new selectOption(displayName, displayName)); 
}
```